# regarding Basel III IRB method for credit risk

Tags: risk, risk-management

Would the exposures between standard method and internal rating based method for credit risk under Basel III remain same?I could not find any documents for IRB approach under Basel III. Is it still evolving?

Comment: https://www.capitaliq.com/media/151103-SP-BaselSecondWave-US-6-29-12.pdf.
On page 9, the article briefly mentioned the growing important role that the accuracy of the internal rating based method plays under Basel III.